# background-image print friendly Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need to use the header image in the print friendly Wordpress functionality

On specific pages, the image gets called from the following code and I need to change the `background-image` so that I am able to display the image:

```
<div class="hero" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $header_image_parent; ?>');">
```

What can I use instead of `background-image`??
Many thanks in advance

Comment: May I suggest a [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=substitute+for+background-image+html)?

Comment: I think that depends on the user's preferences in their browser. How about for the print version have the image be placed with position absolute behind the text, instead of having it as a background? People can still choose not to print images, though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sam. I know that those who chose to print the pages will want the header image on, that is why I need to replace the background-image with something that will allow WordPress to print